# Google-cloud Apis - Compute is not a constructor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using @google-cloud/compute Nodejs client library v2.4.2 but I keep getting an error stating 'Compute is not a constructor' when I do something like:

const compute = new Compute({projectId:'projectId', credentials: 'key-file'});

Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: Did you have require the dependency before?

Comment: Have you tried using a different version of Nodejs?

Comment: Yes, I do have require for the library. And no, I have not used another version, maybe I should try that.

Answer (score 0):

That method has been deprecated, try this instead:

```
const {InstancesClient} = require('@google-cloud/compute').v1;
const computeClient = new InstancesClient();
const the_compute_instance = await computeClient.get({instance: "<instance-name>", project: "<gcp-project-name>", zone: "<gcp-zone>"})
const public_ip = the_compute_instance[0]["networkInterfaces"][0]["accessConfigs"][0]["natIP"]
console.log(public_ip)
```

[GCP Reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-compute/samples/generated/v1/instances.get.js)